# how to create a page in Sharepoint using graph api

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Am trying to create a page under following structure using graph api but unable to create a page due to error. details are below

sites/site-id/sites/subsite-id/lists/list-id i want to create a page under this list-id page

tried POST request

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/drive/root:/{filename}.aspx:/content

{
    "description": "Share your creative work with the global Microsoft community by joining this annual showcase of visual art.",
    "name": "sample.aspx",
    "title": "sample",
    "pageLayout": "article",
    "promotionKind": "page"
}
```

But am getting error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-03-15T18:20:22",
            "request-id": "eed94d8f-a115-4c56-8817-290155ef8e6e",
            "client-request-id": "48557c1e-bfc2-dc2b-12aa-1e80574b9ba1"
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test, there is no such api to create a page under a list currently. Graph api only support to create a page under site. You can refer to following api.

```
POST /sites/{site-id}/pages
```